# How to reset id after deletion sqlite java

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using SQLite in JAVA. I created a table with column id AUTOINCREMENT but I want to reset id after deletion so that no gaps exist between ids. How can I reset it ?

Comment: What problem would that solve? Generally, identifiers should stay stable. Having gaps between identifiers is not a problem.

Comment: Not reusing ids is the entire purpose of autoincrement in sqlite3. (Hint: You usually don't want to use it.). https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: I want to display them so they can guide the user how many rows does he have in his/her database that's why I want the numbers to be consecutive

Comment: Why can't you use `COUNT(*)` instead?  As other commentors have said, normally you shouldn't try to reassign internal row ID's

Answer (score 0):

Although I highly recommend agains, like laalto

> What problem would that solve? Generally, identifiers should stay stable. Having gaps between identifiers is not a problem.

It's possible by itinerating through all records with an auxiliary variable starting at 1 and incrementing. After reseting all id's you need to change the AUTOINCREMENT seed by running this SQL command `DBCC CHECKIDENT('TABLE_NAME', RESEED, LATEST_RECORD)`

**EDIT**

My bad here's the code for SQLite

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET SEQ=NEWSQUENCE WHERE NAME='table_name';
```

Comment: That's SQL Server, not sqlite as tagged in the question.

Comment: what does NEWSEQUENCE represent ?

Comment: NEWSEQUENCE is where the auto increment will start, you don't want to start at 1 because you already have records, you have to use the count of the records that you have so the count start with the next id after the latest record, but do this after updating the ID column. I hope I explained my self well